# How to customize the Jetty management server programmatically

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, port, embedded-jetty

I would like to implement a `JettyServerCustomizer` (or some other similar interface) to customize the management server (running on port 8081). The method `customize(Server server)` of the classes I implemented so far is called only for the main Jetty server (running on port 8080), when the application starts. How can I make it be called for the management server?

Comment: I just want to access the `ThreadPool` used by the management server, so I can monitor it using a custom gauge. This already works for the main server, but I can't get access to the management server or connector.

Answer (score 0):

Enable JMX and/or JMX remote modules on standalone Jetty.

All of the various ThreadPools, along with many other components, will be available in JMX for you to access.

For embedded-jetty, do this ...

```java
Server server = newServer();

MBeanContainer mbContainer = new MBeanContainer(
    ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer());
server.addBean(mbContainer);

ConnectorServer jmx = new ConnectorServer(
    new JMXServiceURL(
        "rmi",
        null,
        1999,
        "/jndi/rmi://localhost:1999/jmxrmi"),
    "org.eclipse.jetty.jmx:name=rmiconnectorserver");
server.addBean(jmx);
```

Comment: Thank you Joakim! I was hoping to find another way to do this, as enabling JMX poses some security concerns.

Do you know if it is possible to get access to the management thread pool by declaring a customizer in a class annotated with `@ManagementContextConfiguration` ? I found this comment in another thread:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2609#issuecomment-265741819

It is not the same case, but it seems to be related. I tried to implement `JettyServerCustomizer` and other customizers in a class with that annotation, but it didn't work.

Comment: Make sure you understand the JMX security risk.  JMX itself, or remote access to JMX.  You can always access JMX via an ssh tunnel with no publicly exposed port.  JMX is used by millions of Jetty instances right now to monitor various aspects of Jetty, the JVM, and other components that also publish on JMX.

Comment: Alright, I will give it a try, as it seems impossible to get access to the management thread pool by other means. I am having a hard time trying to find the beans that show statistics of each thread pool. 

I managed to create an `MBeanServer` and query beans with name `"java.lang:type=Threading"`. Is this the one that provides the information I need? Based on the other names, the other 52 beans don't seem to be related to ThreadPools.

Would you be so kind as to point me to an example of how to get access to thread pool beans?